# How to merge databases on multiple MySQL nodes to a unified virtual database?

Tags: mysql

For I/O throughput's sake, we have multiple tables distributed on multiple MySQL nodes. However, I don't want my clients to find these tables over multiple nodes, I wish to make them feel that there is only one MySQL node, though it might be virtual.

For example, we have table t1, t2 on node A; t3, t4 on node B; t5, t6 on node C, and I want the client could connect to a virtual node V that all the tables t1-t6 could be accessed. Actually, my clients only need read access.

Are there any mature solutions to meet this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found that this problem could be solved by MySQL_Proxy.

I can use a LUA script to let the MySQL_Proxy redirect SQL commands to proper destinations and forward the results back.